# Extract DataFrame from duplicated values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've a DataFrame with a column in which are stored more duplicates related to different data.

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 120 | abc |
| 2 | 121 | def |
| 3 | 122 | ghi |
| 4 | 121 | abc |
| 5 | 120 | def |
| 6 | 121 | def |
| 7 | 122 | abc |
| 8 | 121 | ghi |
| .. | ... | ... |

I don't know the number of duplicates in A and who are they, but I need to extract n-DataFrame for each duplicate, like this:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 120 | abc |
| 2 | 120 | def |
| .. | ... | ... |

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 121 | def |
| 2 | 121 | abc |
| 3 | 121 | def |
| 4 | 121 | ghi |
| .. | ... | ... |

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 122 | ghi |
| 2 | 122 | abc |
| .. | ... | ... |

How I can do this?
Maybe I can use [duplicated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html?highlight=duplicated#pandas.DataFrame.duplicated) but I haven't clear I must use it in my case.

Comment: just create a dictionary based on the unique keys `{k : v  for k,v in df.groupby('A')}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TRY:

```
df_list = [k for _,k in df.groupby('A')]
```

OUTPUT:

```
[     A    B
 1  120  abc
 5  120  def,
      A    B
 2  121  def
 4  121  abc
 6  121  def
 8  121  ghi,
      A    B
 3  122  ghi
 7  122  abc]
```

Use the below code if you also want to `reset the index` of `each dataframe`.

```
df_list = [k.reset_index(drop=True) for _,k in df.groupby('A')]
```

You can use `dict comprehension` if you need group_names:

```
df_dict = {g:k.reset_index(drop=True) for g,k in df.groupby('A')}
```

Dict output:

```
{120:      A    B
0  120  abc
1  120  def,
 121:      A    B
0  121  def
1  121  abc
2  121  def
3  121  ghi,
 122:      A    B
0  122  ghi
1  122  abc}
```